# HTML to print pdf CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML page that I want to convert to pdf (print mode). I got the Header to repeat in every page but I noticed that the header covers the content in the second page. Any one know how to avoid that?

Note: I am using Bootstrap, but I commented it out so I could use my own styles.

SCSS:

```
@media print{
header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
}
main{
  margin-top: 2cm;
}

footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
@page {
  size: auto;
  //margin: 6.35mm;
}
}
```

Fiddle for HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/u1oy0ehj/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`@media print` executes the code only for the print mode. So anything you include inside this is not affected in the normal browser mode. So you can get rid of the `position: fixed;` in the header **only for print mode** so it doesn't behave that way even in the print mode.

**Fixed positioning takes an element out of the document flow, so no fiddling the element will work.**

[JSFiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/u1oy0ehj/1/)

If you want the `position: fixed` then all you can do is push the `<main>` content down **only for print mode**.

```
main{ margin-top: 5cm; } //probably more than what you had given '2cm'
```

Even this can't help you much because in the second page since you have made your header fixed(its out of the document flow), the overflowing contents will think the header doesn't exist and continue as usual giving you an overlapped effect.

Comment: `position: fixed` is for having the header repeat in every page.

Comment: Thanks but `2cm` is just fine. Also, the problem is in the second page, where the content flowing from page 1 is hidden by the header in page 2.

Comment: do you have any webpage where i can test, Fiddle wont help if you want to print and check the second page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="list${MACRO}TopDivRow" class="row">
        
<style>
    @media print{
        body *:not(#list${MACRO}TopDivRow):not(#list${MACRO}TopDivRow *){
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        #list${MACRO}TopDivRow {
            visibility : visible;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
<button onclick="window.print();">
    print
</button>



 ---------------------Explanation-------------------------------- 
    @media print is useful to print a page. 
    #list${MACRO}TopDivRow    - this is the division id which you want to print. 
in the entire body of page, first iam hidding the content which is not belongs to my perticular division.so i have written **visibility : hidden** there. In the second code snippet, iam printing required division, so i have placed **visibility : visible there**.
window.print()    - useful to print the content of window.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use completely JavaScript to print the particular division in your page.here we are using simple swapping logic between original content and particular division.if you want entire page, pass entire page division id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printContent() {
 var printContents = document.getElementById("list${MACRO}TopDiv").innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script>

list${MACRO}TopDiv - this is your division which you want to print
```